# Google Apps Script Spreadsheet too much data - But there isnt

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, limits

Since end of August 2012 scripts that used to work on GAS have stopped working.

Am using JDBC to retrieve records in my MySQl database and show in a sheet.

> Was working and then I started getting "We're sorry, we were unable to
>   process the operation because it contains too much data."

But the dataset in questions is 2400 rows * 35 columns, which is WAY below the 400 000 cell limit, and way below the 256 columns limit per sheet.

Any ideas? Has something changed recently...

Comment: Not sure if this is the final answer, did a office hours hang out with the guys at GAS, and look like this could be a problem with the size of the actual object (memory), rather than the number of rows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the conclusion here is that the

> "We're sorry, we were unable to process the operation because it contains too much data."

error can be caused not only be the amount or rows and columns (cells) in a data set, but also be due to internals issues with memory use of objects being applied to the region.

Comment: Confirmed by Google support, this is due to the size of the JDBC result set, not the spreadsheet size.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a portion of the values at a time, with a `Spreadsheet.flush();` in between each `setValues()`. That solved my problem.

Comment: Yes, it turns out this is a memory constraint with the jdbc connector itself. Total size of the result set. Actually looks like it doesnt have anything to do with the "size" of the spreadsheet (rows/cols).

Comment: In that case, can you page your results using JDBC? I have no experience with it.